# Auto mounting ntfs partition via gnone disks leads to input/output error when renaming files

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab, ntfs

I should preface this by saying there are a couple of posts about this on here but there are no answers so I figured I would post this with a little more context.

The problem only happens when auto mounting the partition. When you rename a file it leads to an input/output error and corrupts the file. This happens to any file in any folder. This happens if you try from the command line also if you do `mv example.file example-new.file`. I am using Gnome Disks utility but I think that just adds an entry to the `/etc/fstab` file so I can only assume it would be the same as me adding the entry myself.

I see a lot of comments in the other posts saying the drive is bad but this drive is perfectly fine. I have to repair it in windows after the error occurs because the file has been corrupted and needs to be removed. Then I can use it in Windows without issues. I can also use it in Ubuntu without issues if I don't auto mount it and just manually mount it by clicking on it in files and then it mounts to `/media/username/Storage` instead of `/mnt/Storage`.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with permissions because the owner when auto mounting is root and the owner when manually mounting is the me. You would assume if it was a permissions issue then you would get a permissions error instead of an input/output error. Also it does say NTFS as the filesystem when I check so I can only assume that it is using the correct driver. Secure boot is disabled and Fast startup is disabled in Windows also.

Here is the contents of `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1052d2a0-d217-49b4-8f46-6b9bb23c545f / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/F8C2-A7E2 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d546474c-e95d-4796-99de-2546f2fded87 /mnt/d546474c-e95d-4796-99de-2546f2fded87 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/33F03B5D2F8EA067 /mnt/Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

If anyone know what the issue may be or can provide any insight it would be appreciated. If you need more context feel free to let me know in the comments below. I'm on ubuntu 23.04. Thanks.

Comment: Gnome-disks does not use  a good set of parameters for most partitions. Make sure in Windows that you have fast startup off, you you can corrupt data. Are you using Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20) If NTFS on internal drive, best to add to fstab, but create mount point with a name you understand, not UUID. Use UUID or label to mount. I have seen this as good set of parameters: `nodev,windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1000`

Comment: Well I tried those options and still the same result. For some reason auto mounting in fstab doesn't work. So I am just mounting the disk with `udiskctl` in `.bash_profile` so it mounts on login and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install the proper driver for ntfs partitions:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Create the directories where to mount your ntfs partitions, for example /mnt/Ntfs and /mnt/Storage

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/Ntfs
sudo mkdir /mnt/Storage
```

Give permissions to the directories:
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /mnt/Ntfs
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /mnt/storage

Edit your fstab and mount the partitions with the following lines:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d546474c-e95d-4796-99de-2546f2fded87 /mnt/Ntfs ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/33F03B5D2F8EA067 /mnt/Storage ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```